# AJAX: Using multiple form entries to delete multiple server files

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a form with a variable number of text boxes that contain an id.  When the user exits the page, files on the server are deleted by a python script (delete.py). The filename of the files to delete contains the id so the id has to be passed to the python script.  If my form has a single id, everything works perfectly and the file on the server is deleted.  If my form has multiple id fields, no files get deleted.  If I use firebug to step through the code, the files gets deleted regardless of the number of id fields.  I don't understand what is going on.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  My onbeforeunload method is below.

```
function deleteFiles()
  {
  var xmlhttp;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }  

  allElements = document.getElementsByName("id");
  for (x=0; x < allElements.length; x++)
  {
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/cgi-bin/delete.py?id=" + allElements[x].value,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
   }  

window.onbeforeunload = deleteFiles;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the request's are being sent too fast.  Try adding 

xmlhttp.async = false;

```
function deleteFiles()
  {
  var xmlhttp;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

  }
  else
  {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }  

  allElements = document.getElementsByName("id");

  xmlhttp.async = false;

  for (x=0; x < allElements.length; x++)
  {
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/cgi-bin/delete.py?id=" + allElements[x].value,true);

    xmlhttp.send();
   }  

window.onbeforeunload = deleteFiles;
```

Let me know your findings

Comment: If I do as you show and have multiple IDs, only 1 file gets deleted on the server.

Comment: I tried this:   xmlhttp.open("GET","/cgi-bin/delete.py?id=" + allElements[x].value,false); and then all files on the server get deleted.  Why does this have to be set to false to get all the files deleted?

Comment: EDIT: that false parameter does that same.   sets the async property to false.  They get deleted because what happens, is in that for loop, you are sending requests to that service.   As the for loop runs, xmlhttp is sending requests so fast, that some of them don't even make it.   Not entirely sure WHY, but that async property set to false means, instead of sending requests asynchronously (at the same time...) send them synchronously (in line...)

Comment: yes, adding false into the actual xmlhttp.open() command worked.  I'm new to AJAX.  Should I be checking the readyState of each send command?

Comment: To be clear:  xmlhttp.async=false caused 1 of the files but not all of them to be deleted.  Adding false into the xmlhttp.open() will delete all files which is what I am shooting for.

Comment: I'd recommend using jquery's native functionality for ajax.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/   You should drop the use of the XMLHttpRequest.   This is the psuedo code... foreach ( element in elements ) { $.ajax("/cgibin/delete.py?id=" + element.value, {async:false})

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will check into it.